# if $\lim_{x\to 0 } f(x)=l$ ,then there is a number $\lambda >0$ and a number $M$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ if $|x-a|<\lambda$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> prove that $\lim_{x\to 0 } f(x)=l$ ,then there is a  number  $\lambda >0$ and a number $M$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ if $|x-a|<\lambda$

my attempt:

$\lim_{x\to 0 } f(x)=l$ means $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \lambda >0 $: if $|x-a|<\lambda$ then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ or $  -|l|-\epsilon\leq l -\epsilon<f(x)<\epsilon+l\leq \epsilon+|l|$

so it suffice to take $M=\epsilon + |l|$

so i think i proved that if $\lim_{x\to 0 } f(x)=l$ then there is  a number $\lambda $ and  number $M$ such that $|f(x)|<M$

**-does my proof is correct ,and if yes ,do i can consider it as a rigorous proof  ?**

Comment: Use `\lim`, not just `lim`

Comment: Take a fixed value of $\varepsilon,$ for example $\varepsilon =1.$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin already i did

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc but it still fine if i don't use $1$ instead $\epsilon$!!

Comment: Ehr, no, you did not. I made the changes for you. I'm letting you know so you use it in the future.

Comment: okay, thank you  i will

Comment: It is fine, but it suffices to apply the proof for one value of $\varepsilon.$ Some people consider $\varepsilon $ a strange creature, but it is a number. Your reasoning gives the conclusion for any value of $\varepsilon>0. $ Why don't you choose your favorite one, perhaps $\varepsilon =\pi^e.$ My favorite is the simplest possible $\varepsilon=1.$

Comment: okay thank you ...